# apply regex in Clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm new to clojure, and I wish to implement a function that will apply a given regex pattern to a given string, for example:

```
(clojure.string/replace "hPPHp123hPHp" (re-pattern "^[PH]+") "")
```

and I'm getting

```
;=> "hPPHp123hPHp"
```

But if I try using

```
(clojure.string/replace "hPPHp123hPHp" (re-pattern "[PH]+") "")
```

I get `;=> "hp123hp"` which of course is the expected result,
However I want to be able to tweak it a little such that

```
(clojure.string/replace "hPPHp123hPHp" (re-pattern "^[PH]+") "")
```

would return something like: `;=> "hp123PhPHp"`
and

```
(clojure.string/replace "hPPHp123hPHp" (re-pattern "[PH]+") "")
```

without the `^` will do a global replacement and produce `"hp123hp"`
Any suggestions on the way to go, and I'm happy to provide further explanations

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#".."` is a regex shorthand syntax

replace-first if you don't want to replace globally

```
user=> (clojure.string/replace-first "hPPHp123hPHp" #"[PH]+" "")
"hp123hPHp"
```

replace globally

```
user=> (clojure.string/replace "hPPHp123hPHp" #"[PH]+" "")
"hp123hp"
```

Comment: what is the regex for catching upper, lower and mixed cases?

Comment: in this case I would go with `[pPhH]+` or `[pPhH][pPhH]` alias `[pPhH]{2}` depends on what you want